# What is the Typescript type of state in React

Tags: typescript

I get a tslint error when I use `any` to pass the `state` in my React application written in typescript to a function.

> no-any: Type declaration of 'any' loses type-safety. Consider replacing it with a more precise type.

```
class AssetDrillDown extends React.Component<{}, IDetailsListAssetsState> {

constructor(props: {}) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    items: _items
  };
}

public componentDidMount(): void {
    this.getData(this);
}

public getData(that: any): void {
    // not relevant code
    that.setState({items: _items});
}
}
```

I would like to not use `any`, and use a type to fix this issue. How can I do that, please guide.

Answer (score 1):

You have already specified that the state of the react component is `IDetailsListAssetsState`.

Thus, if you are passing state in the function, you can do this:

```
public getData(that: IDetailsListAssetsState): void {
  // now you can read `that.items`
  ...
}
```

However, your code for the `getData` suggests you are passing down the `AssetDrillDown` instance instead of the state if you want to do `that.setState({items: _items});`

then you'd do something link this:

```
public getData(that: AssetDrillDown): void {
  // now you can read that.state.items
  ...
}
```

NOTE:
Although there might be a reason for your code example, there is no need to pass down the instance of the class into the same class method. You can simply access the state like this.

```
public getData(): void {
  this.state.items
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define the state as an interface, in which you can define in a type safe manner what you class expects, explained quite well [here](https://charleslbryant.gitbooks.io/hello-react-and-typescript/content/DefinePropsAndStateTypes.html).

The props interface is the first argument inside the generics diamond operator, and the state the second.

```js
interface IHelloFormProps {
    name: string;
    handleChange(event: any): void;
}
interface IHelloFormState {
    inputName: string;
}
...
export default class HelloForm extends React.Component<IHelloFormProps, IHelloFormState> {
...
```